# SharePoint Web Service (asmx) error 500

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, web-services, ajax

I have a problem with a service. I create a custom service with 1 method. When I test it on debug mode it work awesome, but when I call it with $.ajax it give a 50 error:

```
"{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}"
```

Not even get into the service. I have tested as a dummy returning just a simple string and it gives me the same error.

My method code:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod]
        public object GetRespuestas(string idSolicitudServicio)
        {
            Log.Monitorear("*** GetRespuestas - Iniciando");
            List<DocumentosProceso> listDocumentosProceso = new List<DocumentosProceso>();

            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain");
            CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();

            cc.Add(new Uri(Sitio), "Negotiate", credentials);
            cc.Add(new Uri(Sitio), "Basic", credentials);
            cc.Add(new Uri(Sitio), "NTLM", credentials);

            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(Sitio))
            {
                Log.Monitorear("*** GetRespuestas - Iniciando Contexto en sitio: " + Sitio);
                context.Credentials = cc;
                context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                context.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest);

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documentos Licitacion");
                FieldCollection fieldColl = list.Fields;

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery query = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery();
                query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='IdSolicitudServicio' /><Value Type='Text'>" + idSolicitudServicio + "</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Aplica' /><Value Type='Choice'>Externo</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='TipoDocumento' /><Value Type='Text'>Archivo de Respuestas y Aclaraciones</Value></Eq></And></And></Where></Query></View>";
                ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);

                context.Load(listItems);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Log.Monitorear("*** GetRespuestas - Query Ejecutada");

                if (listItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    Log.Monitorear("*** GetRespuestas - Se encontraron " + listItems.Count + " registros");
                    foreach (ListItem doc in listItems)
                    {
                        DocumentosProceso documentosProceso = new DocumentosProceso();
                        documentosProceso.ID =
                            limpiarID((doc["ID"] == null)
                                ? ""
                                : doc["ID"].ToString());

                        documentosProceso.Nombre =
                           limpiarID((doc["FileLeafRef"] == null)
                               ? ""
                               : doc["FileLeafRef"].ToString());

                        documentosProceso.Url =
                           limpiarID((doc["FileRef"] == null)
                               ? ""
                               : doc["FileRef"].ToString());

                        documentosProceso.TipoDocumento =
                           limpiarID((doc["TipoDocumento"] == null)
                               ? ""
                               : doc["TipoDocumento"].ToString());


                        listDocumentosProceso.Add(documentosProceso);
                    }
                }
            }

            return _js.Serialize(listDocumentosProceso);
        }
```

My ajax call:

```
var body = JSON.stringify({IdSolicitudServicio: 09112016122351});
var urlServicio = "http://vmsps2013:800/_layouts/15/SGL_Services/SGL_Service_2.asmx";

$.ajax({
    url: urlServicio +"/GetRespuestas",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: body,
    success: function(data2) {
        console.log(data2); 
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I would appreciate your help

Comment: nevermind already found my error... I'm an idiot. sorry

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just do an ajax request, you must use SP.RequestExecutor. The call is pretty much the same as jQuery ajax. First you declare a new object of RequestExecutor, then u call executeAsync. And here's [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735924.aspx) with usage example.

Your code would be like this:

```
var url = "http://vmsps2013:800";
var urlServicio = "http://vmsps2013:800/_layouts/15/SGL_Services/SGL_Service_2.asmx";
var body = JSON.stringify({IdSolicitudServicio: 09112016122351});
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(url);
executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url: urlServicio,
        method: "POST",
        body: body,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        success: function(data2) {
            console.log(data2); 
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
);
```

Why do you use Client Object Model in your web-service, when you can use Server Object Model? Which is easier to code, in my opinion.

Comment: first that is not true. second my error was the parameter, key sensittive